# I am unable to get over the java.lang.NullPointerException in android studio when using file provider class

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-studio-2.0, android-fileprovider

This is my Manifest file code

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
    </activity>
```

And the code for my new resource xml file is

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
  </paths>
```

My main activity code is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView image;
    private final int CameraKey = 1;
    Context context = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button click_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

        click_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File file = getFile();
                Uri apkURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                        context,
                        context.getApplicationContext()
                                .getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, apkURI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CameraKey);

            }
        });
    }

    private File getFile(){
        File store = new File("sdcard/Digiwrite");
        if(store.exists()){
            store.mkdir();
        }

        File image = new File(store,"Images.jpg");
        return image;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == CameraKey && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            String path = "sdcard/Digiwrite/Images.jpg";

            image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));

        }
    }
```

I keep getting this error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                 Process: com.mukesh.android.digiwrite, PID: 30365
>                                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser
>   android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager,
>   java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:583)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:557)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:399)
>                                                                                     at
>   com.mukesh.android.digiwrite.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:37)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)

I am completely new to Android studio. I have tried various methods available but I don't get how to make file provider work. May I know where I went wrong?

I tried running this code on lower versions using file.getUri() method and it was working fine. So as to make it run on higher versions I have been trying to convert this to use file provider. But I am stuck. Pls help me out.

Comment: Nothing helped?

Answer (score 0):

use this permission in your xml file.

`<uses-permission android:name="com.company.app.fileprovider.READ"/>`

Comment: I did but even then the same error keeps popping up :/

Answer (score 0):

The path specifying XML needs to contain `path` not `paths`. Change it to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<path xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</path>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this inside of your `application` tag

```
<application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
</application>
```